# use of # in Swift 2

Tags: xcode, swift, servicestack

Hi so my friend gave me his client's existing project and it got too much bugs. I have been debugging the app, and just cam across this line of code

```
class func saveFile(#data: NSData, filename: String, directory: NSSearchPathDirectory = .DocumentDirectory) -> Bool {
    var file = filePath(filename, directory: directory)
    return data.writeToFile(file, atomically: true)
}
```

Noticed `#`? So what exactly is `#`?

Here's a screenshot of function with `#` too.

Additional Info: I think they used this library [Service Stack](https://servicestack.net) and I think it's for xamarin only.

[image]

Comment: ServiceStack is a .NET server framework but also can nicely integrate with Swift clients through generating API Data Transfer Object types (DTOs) from within Xcode. [See related documentation here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Swift-Add-ServiceStack-Reference).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Swift 1, `#` was used to give the same external and internal name to a function parameter. For example, the function definition:

```
func save(#data: Float) {
    print(data)
}
```

Was equivalent to:

```
func save(data data: Float) {
    print(data)
}
```

This was removed in Swift 2, and external names must be declared explicitly.

---

External parameter names are used to make function calls more idiomatic. For example:

```
func send(sender: String, receiver: String) {
    print("Sending from \(sender) to \(receiver)")
}
```

Is called like this:

```
send("Cupertino", "New York")
```

By adding external parameters, you can make that function call more idiomatic without changing the body:

```
func send(from sender: String, to receiver: String) {
    print("Sending from \(sender) to \(receiver)")
}
```

Making the code more readable:

```
send(from: "Cupertino", to: "New York")
```

More information in the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html).

Comment: Thanks! So my next move now is to change all of the code. Sadly Edit> Convert is not working

Comment: You could use a regex like `(func [^\(]+\()#\ *([^\:]+)` and replace with `\1\2 \2` to fix it.

Comment: Don't worry, Swift 2.2 still has plenty of `#` if you're feeling hashtag withdrawal. `#file` `#selector` `#available` `#swiftisawesome` `#yolo`